# Is HttpServlet Singleton?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

As per servlet life cycle, first request to container for servlet will invoke `init()` method(only once for first request), and after that it will serve respective `service()` method, and at last(end of life cycle of servlet) `destroy()` method will be called.

Means `init()` and `destory()` will call once in life time of servlet.

My queries are as below :

1. Does the servlet life cycle will be same as container life cycle. So what i understood is once we start tomcat and first request comes for servlet it will invoke `init()` method and once we stop the server(tomcat or webcontainer) it will invoke `destroy()` method.

So from the above it seems that servlet is singleton.

2. When servlet life cycle will be completed. As far i understood it means once you start the server(after first request) the life cycle of servlet will be started and once you stop the server the life cycle of server will be completed?

Please confirm with my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2.2 Number of Instances**

> The servlet declaration which is either via the annotation as
>   described in Chapter 8, “Annotations and pluggability” or part of the
>   deployment descriptor of the Web application containing the servlet,
>   as described in Chapter 14, “Deployment Descriptor”, controls how the
>   servlet container provides instances of the servlet. For a servlet not
>   hosted in a distributed environment (the default), the servlet
>   container must use only one instance per servlet declaration. However,
>   for a servlet implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, the
>   servlet container may instantiate multiple instances to handle a heavy
>   request load and serialize requests to a particular instance. Chapter
>   2 The Servlet Interface 7 In the case where a servlet was deployed as
>   part of an application marked in the deployment descriptor as
>   distributable, a container may have only one instance per servlet
>   declaration per Java Virtual Machine (JVM™)1. However, if the servlet
>   in a distributable application implements the SingleThreadModel
>   interface, the container may instantiate multiple instances of that
>   servlet in each JVM of the container.

So going by the above quote from specification and definition of singleton we can't say that Servlet is Singleton